# How to use res.write() and res.end() in next.js 13?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm making a sitemap for my application with next.js 13. I have a large url structure so I need to split the sitemaps but currently next.js 13 makes this really difficult. With next.js 12 I just need to create a sitemap.xml.tsx file then create a sitemap directory with dynamic pages in it to read the broken sitemap links in sitemap.xml.tsx. But in version 13 I can't really find any documentation to do this. Here is the code in next.js 12 I use to get the split sitemap from my api. It uses getServerSideProps to overwrite the interface and documents before rendering.
So is there a way to make next.js 13 also do this? Please help me, I can't find any documentation for using res.write() and res.end() on next.js 13.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ res }) {
    const details = await getSitemap()
    const sitemapURLs = await extractSitemapValues(details);
    let sitemapIndex = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd"
             xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`
             sitemapURLs.map((item) => {
                sitemapIndex+=`
        <sitemap>
            <loc>${item}</loc>
        </sitemap>`
       })
       sitemapIndex+=`</sitemapindex>`;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    res.setHeader(
      "Cache-Control",
      "public, s-maxage=600, stale-while-revalidate=600"
    );
    res.write(sitemapIndex);
    res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  }
```

I looked for the documentation before submitting the question, however couldn't find any.

Comment: There is a useful resource [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/crawling-and-indexing/xml-sitemaps). It basically just explains how to add sitemaps to a Next.js project, and it also uses `res.end()`.

Comment: @FabioNettis
Thank you but, this document only works with next.js 12. The code I wrote is also with next.js 12 and it works, however now I have a new project using next.js 13 but I can't use the above with this version. And I also can't find a way to subdivide the sitemap like I did in next.js 12. :(

Comment: Well, there is a Next.js 13 specific way using the app directory. Probably not what you're searching for but you can find this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap).

Comment: I also looked at this, it will create a sitemap that includes all the urls on the page. This will be good for sites with small url structures, however if there are many urls, the sitemap must be divided into page1.xml, page2.xml, then go to these small sitemaps to get the final link structure that nextjs 13 version instruct. I can't really figure out how to break it down for sites with large url structures :(

Comment: Well for my project I let my CMS create the sitemap files directly and expose them publicly. I then created a GitHub Action that fetches the files from the CMS and commits them to the public folder of my project (hence triggering a redeploy on vercel).

Comment: I am also thinking of this option. But is there any way that newly created files on the public folder will be displayed without having to restart the project? I tried creating a static file while the project was running, but when accessing that file, I got a 404 error.

Comment: Yes and no. If you deploy it on your own machine and have write access, yes you could potentially do this at runtime. Sadly Vercels filesystem is readonly and any write action will simply fail.